# Can an inherited Trailblazer operation's contract alter validations defined by its superclass?

Tags: trailblazer

When a [Trailblazer](http://trailblazer.to) operation is defined by inheritance, it inherits its superclass's contract:

```
class Create < Trailblazer::Operation
  contract do 
    ... 
  end
  ...
end

class Update < Create
  ...
end
```

**Can an inherited Trailblazer operation's contract alter validations defined by its superclass ?**

This question arose because a create operation's contract defined a mandatory property that needed to be optional in the update operation:

```
validates :foo, presence: true
```

The initial thought was to somehow *reverse* this definition in the inherited class but there didn't appear to be a way to do this (it is possible to *ignore* a property in the subclass (`writeable:false` - [book](https://leanpub.com/trailblazer) p61) but there appears to be no way to change its validity criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use an external form in each operation's contract. By extracting the form to an external class, the create operation would include and augment it like so:

```
contract Form do
  validates :upload, presence: true
end
```

and the update uperation would include it simply as:

```
contract Form
```

Now the validations added in `Create` don't apply in `Update`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result by adding an `if` statement to the validator:

```
class Create < Trailblazer::Operation
  contract do
    validates :upload, presence: true, if: Proc.new{ |record| !record.persisted? }
  end
end
class Update < Create
end
```

This runs the validation only if the record has not yet been persisted to the database, so it will be skipped during the Update operation. *(This assumes that you're using ActiveModel and following the normal CRUD usage pattern.)*